# finding for which $c\in \mathbb{R}$ sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

so i am trying to find for which $c\in\mathbb{R}$ this sequence converges:

$a_{1}=c$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{a_{n}^2}{4}$

So i got the basic idea how to do this.
First i found the candidate for limit: which is only one: $L=2$

so then i know i have to use this concept:

$|a_{n+1}-L|\leq k|a_{n}-L|\leq ...\leq k^n|a_{1}-L|$ for $|k|<1$

So i know i left out some things, like $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta>0$ but it's not that important as the problem, i use how sequence is defined and that limit is 2, but i don't know how to proceed.
Any would be appreciated.
Note: i'm looking for which c it will converge, so in this particular example it will converge to 2. The biggest challenge is how to get that $k$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: yeah, my bad. typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|c|< 2\implies a_2=\frac{c^2+4}{4}$ so $|a_1|<a_2<2$, following an inductive reasoning we can show than for $|c|<2$ the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and bounded above by $2$, then converges.

If $|c|=2$ then $a_n=2$ for $n\ge2$.

When $|c|>2$ the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is increasing and unbounded.

Comment: yeah i did that already, i found that limit is 2. but i have to prove it now directly with definiton.

Answer (score 2):

You found the only possible limit candidate correctly: $l = 1 + \frac{l^2}{4}$ implies $l = 2$.

Now, when is the iteration increasing? That is, when is $a_n - \left(1 + \frac{a_n^2}{4} \right) > 0$? If you solve the quadratic, you get that in fact it's strictly increasing everywhere except at $2$. Therefore, if the sequence ever hits $a_n > 2$ then the sequence will just increase away to infinity. That rules out $c < -2$ (which goes greater than two after the second step) and $c > 2$ (which is immediately greater than two).

We'd like to claim that if we start the sequence anywhere in $[-2, 2]$ then we'll end up at $2$. For this, you can use a strengthening of the Contraction Mapping Theorem, which states that if $d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x, y)$ where $f$ is defined on a compact set, then $f$ has a unique fixed point. Alternatively, you can show that $|f(x)| \leq 2$ if $x \in [-2, 2]$; then the $a_n$ form an increasing sequence which is bounded above, so must converge.

Comment: i haven't came across Contraction mapping theorem, 
I am only at first  year of math, so this is quite new for me. I should've pointed out that i can only use basics.

Comment: I added an "Alternatively" which is accessible to anyone who has done even a small part of a first course in Analysis.